# Is there a universal property for homogeneous maps $ \phi(ax,ay) = a^k\phi(x,y) $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, quotient-spaces, universal-property

Let $E,F$ and $G$ be vector spaces over the field $\Gamma$ and let $\phi:E\times F \to G$ be homogeneous map of degree $k \in \mathbb N$, i.e.,
$$
\phi(ax,ay) = a^k\phi(x,y), \qquad \forall x \in E, y \in F a \in \Gamma
$$
Is there universal property for such maps ? i.e., is there a pair $(\odot,H)$ where $\odot$ is a homogeneous map of degree $k$ on $E\times F$ into $H$ (a vector space) such that for every homogeneous map (degree $k$) $\phi$ there is a linear $f$ such that $f\circ \odot = \phi$ ?

My attempt:

Let $C(E\times F)$ be the free vector space over the $E\times F$ and let the $N$ be the subspace generated by all elements of the form
$$
(ax,ay) - a^k(x,y)
$$
Now consider the canonical projection $\pi:C(E\times F) \to C(E\times F)/N$,  then define the linear map $h:C(E\times F) \to G$ such that $h((x,y)) = \phi(x,y)$. It can be shown that $N \subset \ker h$. Then by the universal property of quotient maps there is a unique linear map $f:C(E\times F)/N \to G$ such that $f \circ \pi = h$. If the restriction of $\pi$ to $E\times F$ is denoted $\odot$, then this a homogeneous map of degree $k$, and it follows that $f\circ\odot=\phi$, and if $C(E\times F)/N$ is denoted $H$ then we have the pair $(\odot,H)$.

Please comment!, I would like to know whether there is any mistake, or if something like this universal property of homogeneous maps does exist at all. Thanks in advance!

---

**Added**

I have the following two comments on this construction:

**I**. This construction can be carried out for homogeneous maps $\phi:V_1\times\cdots\times V_n \to W$ provided the subspace $N$ of $C(V_1\times\cdots\times V_n)$ is modified accordingly, i.e., to be generated by all elements of the form $(av_1,\cdots,av_n)-a^k(v_1,\cdots,v_n)$

**II**. The basis of $H$ for the case of one Vector space $n=1$ with *finite* dimension $d > 1$ and over $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$, is *uncountably* infinite. Since such maps are determined by their action on all lines through the origin. To see this, take a basis in $V$, then each direction is determined by $d-1$ numbers, and there is uncountably infinite directions to determine the action of $\phi$ on them.

In contrast to ($p$-)linear maps on $V$ into $V$ (for example), which requires only $d^{(p)}\cdot d$ numbers to determine a ($p$-) linear map, (finite dimensional tensor product space.)

Comment: I do not detect any errors, it seems like you've successfully constructed the universal $k$-homogeneous map out of $E\times F$.

Comment: @BrianShin thanks for checking my proof!

Comment: I wish I could say something more interesting, but I don't have anything right now :(  In any case, nice work!

Comment: Yes, I agree, this is fine.

Comment: Same here. It seems as if you've possibly become a devotee of universal properties, after your struggle with your previous question. They really *are* a great idea, but it helps to get motivated by trying to do something without them.

Comment: Yes, I found this http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/universal-property-of-the-quotient/universal-property-of-the-quotient.pdf

Comment: @JohnHughes thanks for checking this

Comment: @JustinYoung thanks for you as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to help you close out this question, I'm going to put the consensus here: this looks like a good construction of a universal property for homogeneous maps.